Trailing slash in GNU and BSD cp and find commands
What might be a reason that BSD cp and find don't "like" a trailing slash for directory names?
|     |            cp            |            mv            |
|-----|--------------------------|--------------------------|
|     | # to copy dir1/ contents |                          |
|     | cp -a dir1/* dir2/       | # to move dir1/ contents |
| GNU |                          | mv dir1/* dir2/          |
|     | # to copy dir1/ itself   |                          |
|     | cp -a dir1/ dir2/        | # to move dir1/ itself   |
|-----|--------------------------| mv dir1/ dir2/           |
|     | # to copy dir1/ contents | # mv dir1 dir2/ works    |
|     | cp -a dir1/ dir2/        | # same, but I don't      |
| BSD |                          | # consider this syntax   |
|     | # to copy dir1/ itself   | # really correct[^1]     |
|     | cp -a dir dir2/          |                          |

A similar issue with BSD find. It adds a trailing slash after the source path automatically, and so, if, for the sake of consistency[^1], you already added it manually, as in find ./ -type f, the first / will be replaced with // instead. Though it doesn't break anything (at least, until you need to parse it), it looks ugly:
.//file1
.//file2
.//dir1/file3
.//dir2/file4

[^1]: Because the root directory in Unix and Unix-like operating systems is /, I consider a trailing / to be not an excessive or optional but instead a mandatory (though its omission is often forgiven by the tools we use) part of directory names, and so I always refer to them like /usr/bin/ and not /usr/bin (and to refer to their contents, /usr/bin/*).

This question is similar to: cp, trailing slash, and copying to the same vs. to another directory. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Though I think the find behaviour is purely cosmetic - it looks like the implementation just does the equivalent of join("/", [initial_path, node_path]) (except for the root directory). Could they have stripped a / if it was present before joining the two strings? Yes. Do they have to? Except for the root directory /, they don't. And it looks like they only did what was necessary.

According to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24925767 answer on Stack Overflow, usually we should not put a trailing slash after the source directory when using the cp command. And on the first glance (and given that I'm not a really command-line skillful guy), it may look as the reason why BSD cp has its behavior. But then why BSD mv doesn't follow the same behaviour pattern? And therefore it doesn't really seem that the answer on Stack Overflow explains why BSD cp behaves so.

You did read your previous question's comments and answers, right?

@muru, Yes, I did, but I don't really see an explanation there. All is said there is, essentially, "Well, in BSD cp works as rsync, for whatever reason."

Yes, and that is the explanation. What else are you expecting?
